# CSS Child vs Descendant selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am a bit confused between these 2 selectors.

Does the **descendent** selector:

```
div p
```

select all `p` within a `div` whether or not it's an immediate descedent?  So if the `p` is inside another `div` it will still be selected?

Then the **child** selector:

```
div > p
```

Whats the difference?  Does a child mean *immediate* child?  Eg.

```
<div><p>
```

vs

```
<div><div><p>
```

will both be selected, or not?

Comment: I've tried to explain [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22632849/1542290) in detail, can refer just incase if its helpful to anyone...

Answer (score 565, accepted):

Just think of what the words "child" and "descendant" mean in English:

- My daughter is both my child and my descendant
- My granddaughter is not my child, but she is my descendant.

Comment: One important note is that a child selector is going to be faster than descendant selector, which can have a visible affect on pages with 1000's of DOM elements.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd simply add on direct answers to his examples in the question as well -- just to make it ridiculously clear.

Answer (score 55):

Yes, you are correct. `div p` will match the following example, but `div > p` will not.

```
<div><table><tr><td><p> <!...
```

The first one is called [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) and the second one is called [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors).

Answer (score 28):

Bascailly, "*a b*" selects all b's inside a, while "*a>b*" selects *b's* what are only children to the *a*, it will not select *b* what is child of *b* what is child of *a*.

This example illustrates the difference:

```
div span{background:red}
div>span{background:green}

<div><span>abc</span><span>def<span>ghi</span></span></div>
```

Background color of *abc* and *def* will be green, but *ghi* will have red background color.

**IMPORTANT:** If you change order of the rules to:

```
div>span{background:green}
div span{background:red}
```

All letters will have red background, because descendant selector selects child's too.

Comment: The "Important" section that you added makes this answer complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

**In theory:** 
Child => an immediate descendant of an ancestor (e.g. Joe and his father)

Descendant => any element that is descended from a particular ancestor (e.g. Joe and his great-great-grand-father)

**In practice:** try this HTML:

```
<div class="one">
  <span>Span 1.
    <span>Span 2.</span>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="two">
  <span>Span 1.
    <span>Span 2.</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
span { color: red; } 
div.one span { color: blue; } 
div.two > span { color: green; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X343c/1/

Comment: Interesting on which browser you tested it, since it appear to work indeed

Comment: FYI, CSS in answer does not match with CSS in JSFiddle (`red` and `blue` swapped).

Answer (score 7):

Be aware that the child selector is not supported in Internet Explorer 6.
(If you use the selector in a jQuery/Prototype/YUI etc selector rather than in a style sheet it still works though)

Comment: i am thinking i use that in css. but in jquery i detect if browser is ie6 (in jquery can i do this? or do i need to use <!--[if IE 6]>) and add a class

Comment: jquery do feature sniffing rather than browser sniffing so I don't think you can detect if browser is ie6. And you shouldn't. Best thing is to include an additional style sheet for ie6 with conditional comments like you described.

Answer (score 7):

```
div p
```

Selects all 'p' elements where at least one parent, grandparent etc. is a 'div' element

```
div > p
```

It means immediate children
Selects all 'p' elements where the parent is a 'div' element

Answer (score 4):

The difference between all selectors by visual DOM tree:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`div > p` matches `p`s that have a `div` parent - `<div><p>` in your question

`div p` matches `p`s that have a `div` ancestor (parent, grandparent, great grandparent, etc.) - `<div><p>` and `<div><div><p>` in your question

Answer (score -1):

CSS selection and applying style to a particular element can be done through traversing through the dom element
[Example

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/caravinden/ypct2vds/)

```css
.a .b .c .d{
    background: #bdbdbd;
}
div>div>div>div:last-child{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>The first paragraph.
 <div class='b'>The second paragraph.
  <div class='c'>The third paragraph.
   <div class='d'>The fourth paragraph.</div>
   <div class='e'>The fourth paragraph.</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```