# CSS children Selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Lets say I have the following HTML

```
<div id="div1">
....
<span class="innercontents">...</span>
....
</div>
```

Can I select just the child  of the parent ID?

Could I do something like

```
#div1 span
{
...
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Sorry for any confusion. I should have been more clear. In the above example I would like to just select the  tags that fall under that specific

Comment: What should the selector match? The <div> or the <span>? (If the <div>, then what you're asking for isn't possible.)

Comment: `#div1 > .innercontents`

Comment: "Can I select just the child classes of the parent ID?" => that sentence is very confusing.

Comment: `#div1 > .innercontents`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182189/css-child-vs-descendant-selectors

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
#div1 > .innercontents /* child selector */
```

The above will select these ids from the following HTML: `c and d`

```
<div id="div1">
   <div id="a">
     <span id="b" class="innercontents"></span>
   </div>
   <span id="c" class="innercontents"></span>
   <span id="d" class="innercontents"></span>
</div>
```

if you want all descendents selected such as `b, c, and d` from the above HTML then use

```
#div1 .innercontents
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `#div1 > .innercontents`. This is the immediate descendent selector, or child selector.

This is the best reference for CSS selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: `#div1 .innercontents` is a descendant selector, not a child selector.

Comment: #div1 > .innercontents then, for immediate descendents.