# What does ">" mean in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “>” mean in CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-mean-in-css-rules)

What does the `>` symbol mean in CSS? I noticed it in my Wordpress blog theme and want to know what it is doing.

```
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    background: #efefef;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    background: #f9f9f9; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f9f9f9), to(#e5e5e5)); /* Older webkit syntax */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    color: #373737;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

it means that only "first nested" elements will be targeted ("child" elements), for example

```
   <div id="a">
       <div id="b">
         <div id="c">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

if you write

```
#a div{
 background: red;
}
```

then both #b and #c will be red, but if you use > like

```
#a > div{
 background: red;
}
```

then only #b will be red, #c will not.

Comment: I think your answer would be even more helpful if you added another `div` with `id=d` under the `id=a` `div` to *visually* show all `child` elements will be selected. :)

Answer (score 12):

That is a child selector (also called a child combinator). You can find out more about selectors on the website of the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C), where you can read the [CSS2 entry on the child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)
or you can skip straight to the [CSS3 entry on the child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators).

Also, here's a great quote from another SO question about [CSS Child vs Descendant selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182189/css-child-vs-descendant-selectors):

> Just think of what the words "child" and "descendant" mean in English:
>
> - My daughter is both my child and my descendant
> - My granddaughter is not my child, but she is my descendant.

Comment: The CSS2 selector specification has been superseded by the CSS3 spec as it's now a Recommendation (also with a pretty cool URL): http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors

Answer (score 3):

`li > a` matches any a element that is a child of li.
See [W3C CSS page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) for any selectors.