# What is the difference between these two style rules?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Child vs Descendant selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182189/css-child-vs-descendant-selectors)

So, what's the difference here?

```
div a {
  /* Styles here */
}
```

and

```
div > a {
  /* Styles here */
}
```

I really don't understand.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7pn7z/ more: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`space` is the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators), while `>` is the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators). *Child* means direct descendant, *descendant* means a node somewhere in the subtree of the parent element, no matter how deep.

Answer (score 2):

To put it in plain words:

```
div a {/*properties*/}
```

This would select and apply the given style to all the 'a' elements in a 'div'.

---

The '>' symbol is the 'Child Combinator':

```
div > a {/*properties*/}
```

This will select *only the direct child* 'a' tags inside the div.

For instance:
css:

```
div > a {color: red}
```

html:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Link One</a>
    <span>
        <a href="#">Link Two</a>
        <a href="#">Link Three</a>
    </span>
    <a href="#">Link Four</a>
</div>
```

Here, red color will only be applied to 'Link one' and 'Link Four'. 'Link Two' & 'Link Three' are not selected since they are nested inside a 'span' element.

Play around with them: http://dabblet.com/gist/3730661

You can read more about CSS selectors here: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: You have misinterpreted the first selector.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I missed that! I'll be more careful next time. ;)