# Video.js controls at the top and pause doesn't function

Tags: css, video.js

I have my video-js player in a percentage width container, and it's finally resizing beautifully.  However the controls are placed at the top of the video instead of the bottom, and the pause button will not work.  Slider, volume, and fullscreen all work, but not pause.  I've tried both 4.2 and 4.2.1 with no luck.  If I use the version hosted here: "http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" the pause works, but the controls are still placed at the top.

I've tested this in both firefox and chrome with no luck.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2.1/video.js"></script>
<script src="vidjs/z-skin.css" rel="stylesheet"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.BCLvideoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}
* html .BCLvideoWrapper {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.BCLvideoWrapper div,
.BCLvideoWrapper embed,
.BCLvideoWrapper object,
.BrightcoveExperience {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="indexvid">
   <div class="BCLvideoWrapper">
<video id="QuickReel" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
 controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="auto" poster="images/reelthumbnail.jpg"
data-setup="{}"> 
 <source src="media/reel.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="media/reel.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
</div><!--BCL--></div><!--indexvid-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.BCLvideoWrapper div` selects all divs that are *descendants* of `.BCLvideoWrapper`. As the video.js player consists of many divs (take a look in your browser's dev tools) this style has the unintended consequences you're seeing.

You should use `.BCLvideoWrapper > div` instead to match only divs that are (immediate) *children* of `.BCLvideoWrapper`, i.e. the div that video.js inserts in place of the original `<video>` element. The divs within that div won't match the rule.

```
.BCLvideoWrapper > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Alternatively you could use `.BCLvideoWrapper > .video-js` to match just children with the `.video-js` class -- this would also match the unmodified `<video>` element in the event that javascript is disabled.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1182189/740233) for an expiation of the difference between child and descendant selectors