# how to select child elements through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div id="container_security" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 485.40000009536743px;">
        <div class="container_sec_class_container" style="display: block;">
            <div class="cont_sec_sec" style="height: 70px;">
                <p class="container_title">
                    Name
                </p>
                <input id="container_name" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                <p class="container_secclass_title">Security Class</p>
                <dl class="container_security_class dropdown">
                    <dt>
                     <span class="parent">
                      <span class="container_secclass_dropdown">Shipping and Receiving</span>
```

In the above code I want to set the title attribute to the bottom most element of above DOM tree.
I want to set titles of all child spans under span whose class is parent.

i m trying the code written below but it is not working

```
var dropDownItem = $('#container_security > div > dl > dt > span > span');
dropDownItem.attr('title', dropDownItem.val());
```

Comment: $('.parent span').attr("title","Temp Title");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using a descendant selector (rather than a brittle series of child selectors) with its class:

```
var dropDownItem = $('#container_security .container_secclass_dropdown');
dropDownItem.attr('title', dropDownItem.val());
```

But note that `val` doesn't apply to `span` elements (only form fields), so the `dropDownItem.val()` part doesn't make sense. Perhaps you wanted `.text()`.

Comment: what about `$('#container_security .container_secclass_dropdown').attr('title', function(){
        return $(this).text()
    })`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: :-) If you want to avoid the variable, sure. It's extra overhead, but nothing that means anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$spanelements = $("#container_security .container_secclass_dropdown");
$spanelements.attr("title", $spanelements.text());
```

**Code Explanation:**

It pretty much selects the div with the id of `container_security` then **looks down and down** for it's descendand and then when it finds an element with the class of `.container_secclass_dropdown` it then selects that element and then it sets it's attribute.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182189/css-child-vs-descendant-selectors) question might help you with what type of selector to choose.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text) question might help you in choosing `.text()` or `.val()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one only if you want to play with last span

```
$('span:last').attr({title:$('span:last').text()})
```

or if with all parent classes spans, then use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('span.parent').children().each(function() {
         $(this).attr({title:$(this).text()});
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this: as you said that you want to set title to all span under span whose class is `parent`

```
$('.parent span').attr("title","Temp Title");
```

if you have more than one span, you try the following..

```
$('.parent span').each(function() { 
    $(this).attr("title",$(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code **selects all the elements** at the **Bottom-most level of the DOM tree** so in this case the bottommost `span` is selected.

### CODE

```
$children = $("body").children();
while ($children.children().length > 0) {
    $children = $children.children();
}
//Now the variable $children is the set of elements at the bottom-most level of DOM.
console.log($children.attr('title', "bottom-most element in DOM tree"));
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8xJHw/1/)**