# Use a space or greater than sign > in CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some CSS code:

```
.welcome div {
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

which does what I want it to do, but also writing it like

```
.welcome > div {
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

will do the very same.

Is there any reason to use one over the other or are they just two different ways of doing the same thing?

Comment: though duplicate, question is more useful than the original one; because if I already knew that they were called child or descendent nodes, why to ask a question. Thanks to a naive question

Answer (score 67, accepted):

No they are completely different, using `>` selects a child element whereas using a space will select a nested element at any level.

For example…

Using `␣`/space in the selector…

```
<div class="welcome">
    <section>
        <div>This will be selected</div>
    </section>
    <div>This will be selected as well</div>
</div>
```

So here, the selector having space will target the `div` at any nested level of the parent element.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx7xV/)</kbd> *(Using `␣`/space)*

```
.welcome div {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #f00;
}
```

---

Using `>`

```
<div class="welcome">
    <section>
        <div>This won't be selected</div>
    </section>
    <div>This will be selected</div>
</div>
```

Whereas here, the selector will target your `div` which is a *child* of the element having `.welcome` but it won't select the `div` which is nested inside `section` tag as it is a grandchild (but not a child) of the outer `div`.

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx7xV/1/)</kbd> *(Using `>`)*

```
.welcome > div {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #f00;
}
```

---

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) : *(For `␣`)*

> The `␣` combinator (that's meant to represent a space, or more
>   properly one or more whitespace characters) combines two selectors
>   such that the combined selector matches only those elements matching
>   the second selector for which there is an ancestor element matching
>   the first selector. Descendant selectors are similar to child
>   selectors, but they do not require that the relationship between
>   matched elements be strictly parent-child.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) : *(For `>`)*

> The `>` combinator separates two selectors and matches only those
>   elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of
>   elements matched by the first. By contrast, when two selectors are
>   combined with the descendant selector, the combined selector
>   expression matches those elements matched by the second selector for
>   which there exists an ancestor element matched by the first selector,
>   regardless of the number of "hops" up the DOM.

Answer (score 14):

They mean two different things.

`.welcome div` means select any `div` which is a descendant of `.welcome`. So it would select all of these `div` elements:

```
<section class="welcome">
    <div>Me</div>
    <div>And me
        <div>And me
            <div>And me too!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

`.welcome > div` only selects a direct child `div` of `.welcome`. So:

```
<section class="welcome">
    <div>It selects me</div>
    <div>And me
        <div>But not me
            <div>And not me either!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Have a read of http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Answer (score 5):

Taken from the [W3C CSS reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html),

> E F
>
> Matches any F element that is a descendant of an E element.

whereas

> E > F
>
> Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.

A child is only the next generation. A descendant is a individual in any following generation.

Answer (score 3):

.welcome div will affect ALL divs inside the "welcome" class... if you use the selector ">" it will affect JUST the children of "welcome".

as an example:

```
<div class="welcome">
    <div class="one">
        <div class="two">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="other">
</div>
```

welcome div will affect "one", "two" and "other"

welcome > div will affect just "one" and "other"

Answer (score 2):

```
.welcome div
```

Selects all  elements inside a an element with "welcome" class

```
.welcome>div
```

selects all  elements where the parent is an element with ".welcome" class

Answer (score 2):

if you use

```
.welcome div
{
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

css will applied to all div descendants of .welcome

if you use

```
.welcome > div
{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

css will be applied only to direct child divs and not their descendants

please find link http://jsfiddle.net/65rL6/

Hope it helps!