# Why is CSS for "ol li" overriding that for "ul li" for a bullet that's in an "ul" (but under an "li" that's in an "ol")?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>A numbered bullet</li>
    <ul>
        <li>An un-numbered bullet</li>
    <ul>
</ol>
```

But it shows like this:

```
1. A numbered bullet
    1. An un-numbered bullet
```

When I do an "inspect element", it shows the `ul li` styles crossed out and overriden by `ol li`. Why?

Comment: Can you show your CSS? Why not change your selector to be `ol > li`?

Comment: @DavidSherret Thank you, that's probably what it should be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1182189/2888561

Comment: HTML markup is getting wrong. `ul` should be inside the `li`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it shows the ul li styles crossed out and overriden by ol li.

Since the `ul` is inside the `ol`, the `li` is a descendant of both the list elements, so both selectors will apply.

The two selectors have equal [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity), so they are applied [in order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order).

You have defined the `ol li` styles after the `ul li` styles in the stylesheet, so they override the earlier ones.

You could use a more specific selector to target the deeper list:

```
ol ul li { }
```

Or you could use a child combinator instead of a descendant combinator:

```
ol > li {}
ul > li {}
```

(Note that it is invalid HTML to have a `ul` as a child of a `ol`. The nested list should appear within a `li`.)

Comment: Thank you. I needed child selectors.

Answer (score 2):

If you put your <ul> *inside* the <li> it will work:

```
<ol>
    <li>First level element, ordered
        <ul>
            <li>Unordered list</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6tGvA/

In your version, the unordered list isn't nested in the li item for proper indentation, thus the ul is ignored.

Comment: I second this answer.  Placing a UL element as a child of a OL but outside of an LI is not valid HTML to begin with, so the browser can freely interpret what that means.  It is unfortunate that HTML does this but it does mean the page will render as opposed to giving you an error.

Comment: This is incorrect. While the markup *is* invalid, browsers error recover consistently from this error so this is not the cause of the problem described. Both styles apply to the deeper li in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6tGvA/2/

Comment: the error is because it's essentially converting the ul tag to a span element and then interpreting the il as part of the ordered list parent

Comment: It is not converting the ul to a span, it is constructing the DOM exactly as described by the markup (despite it being invalid): http://note.io/1kMdOWM

Comment: 'essentially' is wrong, 'not even remotely' would be more accurate. You can tell that the selector for the ul is not being ignored because the question describes it as appearing crossed out in the inspect element view - that means it is being applied and then overridden.