# Difference between ">" and " " selector in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm confused about this two selector in css

In ***W3schools CSS Selector Reference*** said:

> element element like `div p` : Selects all `<p>` elements inside `<div>` elements

and

> element>element like `div > p` : Selects all `<p>` elements where the parent is a  element

what's difference between this two definition?

Comment: > is a direct children selector

Comment: CSS & jQuery selector almost similar look less than `(>)` how to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182189/css-child-vs-descendant-selectors?rq=1

Comment: can you explain more about this? what's direct children selector?

Comment: A similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182189/css-child-vs-descendant-selectors?rq=1

Comment: @user3087607: Here is a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/01e09ak6/) to visually see the difference. `>` selects only the `p` element that is directly under the `div` and not nested within a different parent.

Comment: thanks, i think i figured out what's difference between these two selector. but 'div + p' seems to be similar to 'div>p' . what's difference between these two selector?

Comment: @user3087607: `+` is a sibling selector. It selects a `p` that directly follows a `div` tag. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/01e09ak6/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
E F Matches any F element that is a descendant of an E element.
E > F   Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.
```

You may be more clearer from this picture:

[image]

Comment: thanks, that was great. can you define 'div + p' for me?

Comment: + is used for immediate sibling and ~ is used for any next siblings

Comment: see this picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pvW6Q.jpg