# Multiple classes or IDs in one jQuery statement used for addressing one specific element

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

I would like to know how I can have more then one ID and one class in one jQuery statement. So let's say I have this one:

```
<div id="content1">
    <div id="names">
        <div class="subheader">
            Other names
        </div>
        <div class="subtext">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="age">
        <div class="subheader">
            Age
        </div>
        <div class="subtext">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content2">
    <div id="names">
        <div class="subheader">
            Other names
        </div>
        <div class="subtext">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="age">
        <div class="subheader">
            Age
        </div>
        <div class="subtext">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I now do something like:

```
$("#content #names.subtext").html("some name");
```

I also tried to use names and age as class. But there I have the same trouble. So is this issue really one or how should that usually be solved instead?

Comment: `$("#content #names .subtext").html("some name");` or `$("#content #names .subtext").text("some name");`

Comment: Thanks but no solution because I have some other top ID's additional to "conent".

Comment: It works just the same way as Tyranicangel's answer, so either both works or both doesn't work.

Comment: You are right that is also working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements are direct childs of your content you can use the child-selector of css:

```
$('#content > #names > .subtext').html('some name');
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xkqd3ch6/)

Comment: Indeed that's even shorter. But could you tell me if there is a difference to `$('#content #names .subtext').html('some name');` because is also working.

Comment: `x > y` matches direct child of the parent elemtent, whereas `x y`matches when an element y is an arbitrary descendant. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1182189/4202224). So because of the specification, the child selector is going to be faster on large sites

Answer (score 1):

You can use .find

```
$('#content').find('#names').find('.subtext').html('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

As IDs must be unique, you will have to use classes instead:

```
<div id="content1">
    <div class="names">
        <div class="subheader">
            Other names
        </div>
        <div class="subtext">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="age">
        <div class="subheader">
            Age
        </div>
        <div class="subtext">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content2">
    <div class="names">
        <div class="subheader">
            Other names
        </div>
        <div class="subtext">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="age">
        <div class="subheader">
            Age
        </div>
        <div class="subtext">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



$(".names .subtext").html("some name");
```

Comment: Actually I already had this one. But I plan to have some other top id's additional to "content". So no solution for me but thanks.

Comment: Humm, do you want to target multiple ids at the same time, instead of nested?

Comment: You can't have repeated IDs in the same page context. You need to use classes instead. I also edited my answer.