# CSS child selector depth

Tags: css

I have the following HTML code :

```
<div class="class1">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <div class="class2">
       <input type="text">
       <input type="text">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want all the input fields to have a margin-left : 10px;

I know I can do the following :

```
.class1 > input {margin-left:10px}
.class1 > .class2 > input {margin-left:10px}
```

But I was wondering if I could do this with one line of CSS

```
.class1 >>> input {margin-left:10px}
//>>> meaning "has .class1 in his familly tree"
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can just remove the [direct descendant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182189/css-child-vs-descendant-selectors):

```
.class1 input {
    margin-left:10px
}
```

Alternatively if you wish to keep the direct descendant then you can have multiple selector rules:

```
.class1 > input,
.class1 > .class2 > input {
    margin-left:10px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way of applying CSS to child elements (for example)-

```css
.class1 input {
 margin-left:15px;
}

.class1 > input {
    background-color:lightgreen;
}

.class1 > .class2 > input {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <div class="class2">
       <input type="text">
       <input type="text">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS selectors are very flexible. for your requirement you can creator a selector as follows.

```
.class1 input {
    margin-left:10px
}
```

above selector will select all child `input` fields within `.class1` div. it will also select input fields which are within `.class2` as `.class2` is also child of `.class1`