# How to find element with specific parent?

Tags: python, css-selectors, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

I have some HTML like:

```
<div class='cl1'>
    <div class='cl2'>text_1</div>
    <div class='cl3'>
        <div class='cl2'>text_2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to find any items of cl2 class that have cl1 as parent, so i need to get **text_1** but not **text_2**. In simple css it should be like this:

```
'div.cl1>div.cl2'
```

but I use *robobrowser* and *BeautifulSoup*, and when I try

```
soup.select('div.cl1>div.cl2')
```

it says that css selector is wrong.

Comment: What is your exact error?

Comment: Can you try it with spaces, something like this maybe? 'div.cl1 > .cl2'

Comment: The `div` with `text_2` is a child of `cl1` as well...

Comment: @Jan, it is not a child, it is a descendant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182189/css-child-vs-descendant-selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selector is on the right track, you just need to space out the classes i.e `div.cl1>div.cl2` should be `div.cl1 > div.cl2`:

```
In [5]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [6]: html = """<div class='cl1'>
    <div class='cl2'>text_1</div>
    <div class='cl3'>
        <div class='cl2'>text_2</div>
    </div>
</div>"""

In [7]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [8]: soup.select_one("div.cl1 > div.cl2") # good 
Out[8]: <div class="cl2">text_1</div>
In [9]: print(soup.select_one("div.cl1>div.cl2")) # bad
None
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """
<div class='cl1'>
    <div class='cl2'>text_1</div>
    <div class='cl3'>
        <div class='cl2'>text_2</div>
    </div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
divs = [div
        for div in soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'cl2'})
        if 'cl1' in div.parent["class"]]

# [<div class="cl2">text_1</div>]
```