# document.querySelector whats " * " doing?

Tags: html, chatbot

I saw a sample which looked like this:

```
document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
```

I know what it does (sets the focus into the sendbox of the webchat), but I dont understand what the " * " stands for. I know that #webchat is the "parent".

I implement the whole webchat with an external javascript, so I didn't code anything of the DOM.
The sendbox's id is "webchat-sendbox-input" so nothing with a " * ".

Thats how the DOM looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#universal-selector):

> The universal selector, written as a CSS qualified name [CSS3NAMESPACE] with an asterisk (* U+002A) as the local name, represents the qualified name of any element type. **It represents any single element** in the document tree in any namespace (including those without a namespace) if no default namespace has been specified for selectors. If a default namespace has been specified, see Universal selector and Namespaces below.

or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors):

> The CSS universal selector (*) matches elements of any type.
>
> ```
> /* Selects all elements */
> * {
>   color: green;
> }
> ```

or even [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp) (which manages to correctly cover the basics for documents without namespaces):

> Select all elements, and set their background color to yellow:
>
> ```
> * {
>     background-color: yellow;
> }
> ```

Comment: So basically it tries to focus on every element inside of #webchat?

Comment: @BeschtPlaier — No. Since (a) `querySelector` only returns the first match and (b) It uses a child combinator and not a descendant combinator.

Comment: I think i still don't understand it then. 
When " * " selects all elements and #webchat is the parent, it should select all elements of #webchat, shouldn't it? Or does it try to get as low as possible ? Or am I completly wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182189/css-child-vs-descendant-selectors

Comment: So " #webchat > * " just selects the first element right after #webchat, no matter which kind of element it is?

Comment: No. It selects all the children.

Comment: Oh okay. I think i got it now, thank you very much :) "only returns the first match" confused me.

Comment: **`querySelector`** only returns the first match